# SyntaxError: Unexpected token static

Tags: jasmine, ecmascript-6, jestjs, ecmascript-2016

I'm currently trying to evaluate different testing frameworks that work with React, and it turns out that Jest is on my list. However, I'm trying to use static properties outlined here: https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties.

So, I took the tutorial that is given on the Jest homepage, and added a static propTypes property, my code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class CheckboxWithLabel extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isChecked: false};

    // since auto-binding is disabled for React's class model
    // we can prebind methods here
    // http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.isChecked}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {this.state.isChecked ? this.props.labelOn : this.props.labelOff}
      </label>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = CheckboxWithLabel;
```

When I run the tests (npm test or jest), It throws the following error:

```
➜  jest            
Using Jest CLI v0.8.2, jasmine1
 FAIL  __tests__/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js 
● Runtime Error
SyntaxError: Desktop/jest/examples/react/CheckboxWithLabel.js: Unexpected token (5:22)
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "*",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "babel-preset-react": "*",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

> Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Class properties are neither part of the `es2015` nor the `react` preset.

You have to load the plugins that handles class properties:

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties
```

And in your `.babelrc` file (next to existing plugins or presets):

```
"plugins": [
   "syntax-class-properties",
   "transform-class-properties"
]
```

Comment: Thanks! There's another error after this with: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..", any ideas?

Comment: Are the plugins specific to Babel 6? I have this working in 5.x just by setting stage 0.
@HappyCry does it point to a particular line?

Comment: @MattMolnar: yes, that is for Babel 6.

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs since Standard ES2015(ES6) classes can only have methods, not properties.
For me, it was resolved by installing **`babel-preset-stage-0`** which adds support for class properties.

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Then configure Webpack (or `.babelrc`) to use this preset:

```
//...
presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
//...
```

**UPDATE:**
As of **Mid-2018**, Babel `env` preset supports *ES2015, ES2016 and ES2017*.
So, you can skip stage-0 preset and instead use the env preset

```
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

And then update your .`babelrc` to

```
//...
presets: ['env', 'xyz']
//...
```

To support latest *ES2018* features like spread operator/async functions, you can add `stage-3` preset.

[**Reference tutorial**](https://digitalfortress.tech/tricks/support-es2018-with-webpack-encore/)