# Bable Not Compiling JSX for Jest/React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

Im trying to setup unit testing with JEST for React.

My current set up is inside Package.json:

```
 "jest": {
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "json",
  "jsx"
]
```

}

And then inside .babelrc I have:

```
{
    "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import", "transform-runtime"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
    }
  }
  }
```

I then run npm test, and it then starts run jest. However, it will error/Fail with :
Test suite failed to run with a error at

```
                 componentDidMount=()=>{
           |                      ^
        25 |         window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
        26 |     }
```

This is telling me that while the test enters the correct Component, it eventually stops at some es2015 syntax.

Do I have something set up wrong? It seems that babelrc is NOT actually transpiling before JEST tries to run its test? Is this correct?
My .babelrc is at the root level.

Comment: It looks like there are some syntax error in your code around the "`componentDidMount`" definition. If your `componentDidMount` is defined as an attribute of an object, you should use `:` but not `=`. Else please show your code here.

Comment: @PhilipTzou That is just the componentDidMount react lifecyle method inside my React component. Running the app, this method works fine with no errors.

Comment: The `componentDidMount=()=>{...}` code doesn't seem correctly. Can you post the context code around it so we can have a deep look of it?

Comment: =()=> syntax is just es6 arrow syntax for a function, this shouldnt be an issue. Even if i do remove it, and set it as componentDidMount(), It will still throw another error: Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Assigning a property inside a class like that is not ES6, it is https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/ which you'd have to explicitly enable if you want it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth a property in a class isn't es6, but im pretty sure arrow syntax is, and that is where it was throwing the error. Unless I'm misunderstanding you. But I'll try that plugin! Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: The syntax error is the `=` sign before the arrow function, not the arrow function. You'd get the same error if you replaced the arrow with any other value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821270/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-static)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [transform-class-properties babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Static class properties are not part of ES2015 and need a separate plugin.